# Normality and integrality of schemes and splitting of map from structure sheaf to derived-pushforward of structure sheaf along proper birational map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, derived-functors, pushforward, integral-extensions

Let $R, S$ be commutative Noetherian rings such that $R$ is a subring of $S$. If $S$ is a normal domain, and there exists an $R$-linear map $\phi: S\to R$ whose restriction on $R$ is the identity map, then it is standard that $R$ is also a normal domain. This leads me to ask the following question:

Let $X, Y$ be Noetherian schemes such that $X$ is an integral and normal, and there exists a proper birational morphism $f: X\to Y$. If the natural map $\mathcal O_Y \to \mathbf Rf_*\mathcal O_X$ is a split monomorphism, then is $Y$ also a normal integral scheme?

Comment: I'm confused by your first sentence: $k[t^2,t^3]\subset k[t]$ is an inclusion of commutative noetherian rings where the latter is a normal domain but the former isn't. What am I missing?

Comment: You’re not missing anything because it’s false. Your example shows that you can take R to be any non-normal domain and simply take S to be the field of fractions.

Comment: @HankScorpio: I meant to add that $R$ is a retraction of $S$ as an $R$-module ... very sorry for the confusion

Comment: @CraniumClamp: I forgot to add that $R$ is a retraction of $S$ ...